# Import twitter not working python

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter-oauth

This is not working for me

```
import twitter

api= twitter.api(consumer_key,consumer_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)
//declared tokens value in the code.
```

It throws error : 'module' object is not callable

I do not want to use tweepy for this.

Comment: import twitter works. It's the next line which fails.

Comment: Assuming you're using [this twitter module](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter), it's `twitter.Api` not `twitter.api`.

Comment: api= twitter.Api(consumer_key,consumer_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)   Still throws error -
AttributeError: module 'twitter' has no attribute 'Api'

Comment: yes I am using same module

Comment: What does `dir(twitter)` or `print(dir(twitter))` output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding which twitter library you are using, I think you want to be doing something like this (example retrieved by doing `import twitter` and then `help(twitter)` in an interactive Python interpreter):

```
from twitter import *
t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(token, token_key, con_secret, con_secret_key))
```

In your case, you are getting and error because `twitter.api` is a submodule of the `twitter` module, and (as the Traceback says) is not callable.

Since it appears that you have the necessary values, you should try plugging them in (in the correct order - not the difference between my example, and the order of the arguments in your example) to `OAuth()` or `twitter.OAuth()` if you don't do a wild import. Then you can pass that `OAuth()` instance to `Twitter`/`twitter.Twitter()` to create your API instance to query.

So in your case, a (potentially) working example might be:

```
import twitter

auth = twitter.OAuth(access_token, access_token_secret, consumer_secret, consumer_key)
api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)
```

I am unable to test this, since I don't want to set up API credentials, but I have used this library in the past. I first learned about this API in [this book chapter](https://github.com/ptwobrussell/Mining-the-Social-Web-2nd-Edition/blob/master/ipynb/Chapter%201%20-%20Mining%20Twitter.ipynb), which contains some helpful examples.

Comment: by using above code I am able to establish connection but while retrieving data it is throwing error. Code is:                                       import twitter                                                                                      auth = twitter.OAuth(access_token, access_token_secret, consumer_secret, consumer_key)
    api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)
    result = api.GetFreinds()                                                                          It is throwing error :  details: {'errors': [{'code': 34, 'message': 'Sorry, that page does not exist'}]}

Comment: @ShringaBais I think the `twitter` library is pretty outdated at this point. You might want have better luck with `tweepy` or `python-twitter`. `tweepy` seems to be well maintained.

Comment: Well the problem is I cannot use tweepy. So need to work with twitter or TwitterAPI.   twitter.api functions are easy to work with  that's why using import twitter

Comment: @ShringaBais also, note that you have a typo in the code in your comment: `result = api.GetFreinds()` I assume should be `result = api.GetFriends()`. However, from looking at the source code, I do not see a `GetFriends()` method as all. See here for examples of how to use the `Twitter()` class: https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter#the-twitter-class